# Ajax call to web service - Missing Parameter error

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services

I am trying to call a web service from a function using AJAX and keep getting missing parameter error.

I have added console.log() and can see the data with correct parameter name.

I am using the same method in many other functions (i.e., calling web service method from AJAX) and have no issue. I even copy/pasted one that I know is working and just change web service method name (url) and data being passed, same error.

In .asmx:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json]
public string ExportToExcel_TraceLog(string TLData)
{
    string JSONresult = string.Empty;
    do_whatever_with_TLData;
    return JSONresult;

 }
```

In .aspx:

```
function exportToExcel() {
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify({ 'TLData': parseResults });
    var url = '<%= ResolveUrl("../WebService/ABC.asmx/ExportToExcel_TraceLog") %>';
    console.log(jsonResult);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({ TLData: parseResults }), // I tried "data: jsonResult" too
        }).done(function (result) {
            // ...
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        });
    }
```

This is what I see in browser in response to console.log(), clearly showing the parameter TLData

```
{"TLData":[{"RequestType":"d","NodeID":"E8","MessageLength":37,"Timestamp":"2023-07-25T07:47:03.566", ...}]},

}
```

This is the error I see:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: TLData.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExportToExcel_TraceLog` are trying to deserialize the json object, try passing a string with double quotes escaped inside a json object:

```
function exportToExcel() {
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(parseResults);
    jsonResult = jsonResult.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"")
    var url = '<%= ResolveUrl("../WebService/ABC.asmx/ExportToExcel_TraceLog") %>';
    console.log(jsonResult);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: '{"TLData":"' + jsonResult + '"}'
        }).done(function (result) {
            // ...
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        });
    }
```

Then you have to deserealize everything again in the WebMethod.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post(JsonElement TLData)
{
    //work with json data 
    return TLData.ToString();
}
```

Comment: My bad! I was trying to stringify something that was already stringified version of another AJAX operation! In another jQuery function I had parseResults = JSON.stringify(result.d); and then I was doing data: JSON.stringify(TLData: parseResults). I will now proceed to wake up.